# How to export entire object material and texture as an image?

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, image, texture-painting

I am making a gun skin for a game and I want to export the material texture node setup as an image in its UV format. I have no clue how to do this.

Gun skin:
[image]

node setup:

[image]

Comment: Hello, you need to bake the various maps: Diffuse, normals, roughness, etc

Comment: You can learn how to bake images elsewhere on this site, but that's not the entirety of what you asked: You need to recreate the material in the game engine.  Materials are specific to each engine that uses them.  If the game engine doesn't support a feature you need, you need to write a new shader.  If the game engine doesn't allow to you to change shaders, then you need a new game engine.  See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures